# Redshift query output too big for RAM

Tags: sql, python-3.x, amazon-redshift

I have a redshift query the output of which is too big to fit into the RAM of my EC2 instance. I am using `psycopg2` to execute the query. If I use the limit keyword will the rows repeat if I increment the limit ?
Say I enforce a limit of `0,1000` at first and get a block, then I enforce a limit of `1001,2000`. Will there be a repetition of rows in those two blocks considering redshift fetches data parallelly ?
Is there a better alternative to this ?

Comment: You should always use `LIMIT` with `ORDER BY`.  And the `ORDER BY` should have keys that uniquely define each row.  Then you don't have to worry about duplication.

Comment: First of all do you actually need to LOAD THEM ALL into RAM? You can PROCESS the whole lot just by buffering and pipelining, without actually load everything simultaneously.

Comment: Alternatively, you can run the query mutliple times (assuming you add `ORDER BY`). However, this strategy may not work correctly if the database is being modified in the meantime. Your multiple queries may suffer from gaps or duplicity in the result if the data is modified by other processes.

Comment: I've just looked properly at the question; note that Redshift does not support a row-range for `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to DECLARE a cursor to store the full results on Redshift and then FETCH rows from the cursor in batches as you need.  This way the query only runs once when the cursor is filled.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/declare.html (example is at the bottom of the page).

This is exactly how BI tools like Tableau get data from Redshift - in blocks of 10,000 rows.  Using cursors prevents the tool/system/network from being overwhelmed by data as you possibly select very large result sets.

Comment: But remember that cursors are bad news for Redshift.  The entire query result is produced and stored on the leader node until the cursor has finally conveyed the lot to the client.  This is bad news for everyone else on the cluster, and this is why you are limited to one cursor per session.  The general advice is not to use them, and my personal very strong advice is not to use Tableau (or other BI tools) on Redshift, at all.

Comment: Just wow.  Every query has its results stored on the leader node until it can be moved out over the network.  Browning the network out pushing large results out continuously can make the leader unresponsive.  The only thing better is to not produce large results through the leader which limits you to parallel-off unloads.  Life is full of choices and workloads to perform.  Everyone is entitled to their own opinion.

Comment: This would've solved my problem but unfortunately my cluster isn't big enough to carry this amount of data in a cursor. Thanks anyways @BillWeiner

Comment: OK if you results are that large then you will want to UNLOAD the data (parallel off) to S3.  Then parse the S3 objects from your ec2 instance.